# Data sync from different SQL Server versions databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, data-synchronization

So I have a SQL Server 7.0 database that can not be upgraded. it is only allowed to have data read and written in it.
I created a SQL Server 2008 R2 database which is the same structure. I want to synchronize the data between both so whatever happens on the SS7.0 happens in the SS2008 R2, and vice versa, is there a way to do so? 
I'm not asking for a ready answer, I just want a trail to follow, tips and such. So far I only managed to export a copy of the data with bcp, but I can't do it each time

Comment: Publisher has to be higher or equal version than subscriber in order to be supported. SQL Server 7.0 is totally not supported. So you are on your own. I guess, your as is implementation of bcp out and bcp in data is the way or look for a 3rd party who still supports this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a lot of articles about MS-SQL Server 7.0 replication in Technet and MSDN.

[Two-Way Replication with SQL Server 7.0](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224784(v=sql.80).aspx)

[Microsoft SQL Server 7.0 Replication Made Easy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226171(v=sql.70).aspx)

[Replication for Microsoft SQL Server Version 7.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226168(v=sql.70).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would 'start' by doing some Internet searches for 'sql server 7 transactional replication'

[This article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224784(v=sql.80).aspx) appears to have quite a bit of useful information about this topic, but I'm not 100% sure if everything in the article is still relevant.

Comment: believe I did and am still doing reasearch, but I don't seem to find what I'm looking for, I just need steps or a track to follow

Comment: I found this article which 'might' help - it may be trial and error - http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/1438201/Setting-Up-Transactional-Replication-A-Step-by-step-Guide.htm